# How to make function in locals?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Im trying to make a function in express locals, so i can render it in ejs partial. Here is my code:

```
res.locals.balance = async (currentUser) => {
    if(currentUser != undefined){
        connection.query("SELECT balance FROM users WHERE email = ?", [currentUser], function(error, results){
            if(error){return error;}
            return results[0].balance
        })
    } else {
        return "0";
    }
}
```

this code returns Object promise, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise.

reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description

You can get balance by doing something like

```
const balance = await balance(currentUser);
```

Comment: I have to run this in an async function, and if run this in async function im getting promise once again, my ejs code: <%= await balance(user) %>